# Get value of sibling - extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

Hello I have a checkbox and hidden element placed in the same table data cell. When the checkbox is checked, I would get its id using Ext.query method. I have the ID of the whole record that maps to the database in the hidden element which is sitting next to this checkbox element.

I would need to retrieve the value of this element. I could use next() in JQuery to retrieve this, I am newbie to extjs and have no idea how I would do to retrieve this in EXTJS.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="delete_value_{0}" id="delete_value_{0}"/> 
<input type="hidden" name="hidden_value_id_{0}" id="hidden_value_id_{0}" />
```

This is how they are placed into a table data cell(td).

{0} would dynamically set the counter value. (since rows would be generated dynamically)

Answer (score 3):

You can use next - http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Element&member=next

```
var other = Ext.fly(box).next('input');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the element with `Ext.get("hidden_value_id_{0}")`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the checkbox id and you want to retrieve the hidden input's value, following little line should do the trick -

```
Ext.DomQuery.selectNode('input[id="delete_value_{0}"] ~ input').value
```

Reference - [DomQuery](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.DomQuery)